# Smooth function with vanishing derivatives

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $f:(a,b)\to\mathbb R$ be a smooth function, that is, $f\in C^{\infty}((a,b))$. Suppose:

Case 1: There exists $n\in \mathbb N$ such that $\frac{d^n}{dx^n}f(x)=0$ for all $x\in(a,b)$.

Case2: For each $x\in(a,b)$, there exists $n_x\in\mathbb N$ such that $\frac{d^{n_x}}{dx^{n_x}}f(x)=0$.

Prove in either case, $f$ is a polynomial.

Of course case 2 implies case 1, but I want to know whether there is a less complicated or more fundamental proof for the both cases.

Comment: Hint: For case $(1)$, solve the n-th order ODE.

Comment: @Micah Are you sure (2) is false? Counterexample?

Comment: @AnalysisStudent0414 You are right, my fault…

Comment: You can find a proof of the second case in this MO question: [If $f$ is infinitely differentiable then $f$ coincides with a polynomial](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/34059/if-f-is-infinitely-differentiable-then-f-coincides-with-a-polynomial).

Answer (score 0):

Case (1): solve the ODE. You know the solution is unique up to some constants which will turn out to be the coefficients of the $(n-1)$-th grade polynomial

Case (2): this is a bit tricky. Consider a dense numerable set A (for instance $(a,b) \cap \mathbb{Q}$  ).

There are two cases:

**a) $\displaystyle \sup_{a \in A} n_a = c \in \mathbb{N}$**

Since the c-th derivative $g=\frac{d^c}{dx^c}f$ is continuous, chosen $\varepsilon >0$, there is some $\delta$ such that $|x-y| < \delta$ implies $|g(x)-g(y)|<\varepsilon$. This implies that $g$ is $0$ on all $(a,b)$ by a classic $\varepsilon /2 $ argument.

**b) $\displaystyle \sup_{a \in A} n_a = +\infty \in \mathbb{N}$**

We have to show this is not possible. I thought I could split $(a,b)$ in many intervals and then use continuity, but it doesn't work.
I'll keep thinking about it, I appreciate hints!

**(INCOMPLETE ANSWER)**